"Can't add file.... The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." when running dotnet-docker aspnetapp
System Info:
.NET SDK:
 Version:           8.0.205
 Commit:            3e1383b780
 Workload version:  8.0.200-manifests.818b3449

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19045
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.205\

.NET workloads installed:
There are no installed workloads to display.

Host:
  Version:      8.0.5
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       087e15321b

.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.423 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  8.0.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  8.0.205 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]


Windows 10 laptop.

Docker Desktop 4.3

Visual Studio IDE (although docker build for this project don't work in CLI either)

Seemingly no firewall issue (not 100% sure). There was some issue in 2017 that Microsoft closed regarding this.


Problem Statement:
I am running through this basic application from Microsoft and I get stuck on 'docker build -t aspnetapp'. I get all sorts of weird errors primarily Can't add file...[file/path/here]...The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. I looked for processes in Process Monitor and found the docker.exe blasting each of those files. I have no idea why this is going on, as other containers seem to run fine.  

time="2024-06-04T17:17:09-05:00" level=error msg="Can't add file \\\\?\\C:\\code\\simple-dotnet6-app-running-windows-container\\dotnet-docker\\samples\\aspnetapp\\.vs\\aspnetapp\\FileContentIndex\\bec4c4e8-54fd-4b4d-b17f-f94c9982374f.vsidx to tar: open \\\\?\\C:\\code\\simple-dotnet6-app-running-windows-container\\dotnet-docker\\samples\\aspnetapp\\.vs\\aspnetapp\\FileContentIndex\\bec4c4e8-54fd-4b4d-b17f-f94c9982374f.vsidx: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

time="2024-06-04T17:17:09-05:00" level=error msg="Can't add file \\\\?\\C:\\code\\simple-dotnet6-app-running-windows-container\\dotnet-docker\\samples\\aspnetapp\\.vs\\aspnetapp\\v17 to tar: archive/tar: missed writing 1694429 bytes"
time="2024-06-04T17:17:09-05:00" level=error msg="Can't add file \\\\?\\C:\\code\\simple-dotnet6-app-running-windows-container\\dotnet-docker\\samples\\aspnetapp\\.vs\\aspnetapp\\v17\\.futdcache.v2 to tar: archive/tar: missed writing 1694429 bytes"
time="2024-06-04T17:17:09-05:00" level=error msg="Can't add file \\\\?\\C:\\code\\simple-dotnet6-app-running-windows-container\\dotnet-docker\\samples\\aspnetapp\\.vs\\aspnetapp\\v17\\.suo to tar: archive/tar: missed writing 1694429 bytes"
time="2024-06-04T17:17:09-05:00" level=error msg="Can't add file \\\\?\\C:\\code\\simple-dotnet6-app-running-windows-container\\dotnet-docker\\samples\\aspnetapp\\.vs\\aspnetapp\\v17\\DocumentLayout.json to tar: archive/tar: missed writing 1694429 bytes"
time="2024-06-04T17:17:09-05:00" level=error msg="Can't add file \\\\?\\C:\\code\\simple-dotnet6-app-running-windows-container\\dotnet-do


doing the same exercise but getting a different error... did you figure this out? No answers below
Sending build context to Docker daemon  10.97MB
Step 1/13 : FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build failed to parse platform : "" is an invalid component of "": platform specifier component must match "^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+$": invalid argument

No I have not figured it out sorry :(
